# Setting option value as array index in a select with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

I want to create a select tag using rails `collection_select` or `options_for_select` with the items of an array which are not model based. The value of the option should be the array index of each item.

Example: desired output for `['first', 'second', 'third']`:

```
<select id="obj_test" name="obj[test]">
    <option value="0">first</option> 
    <option value="1">second</option> 
    <option value="2">third</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I mentioned in the question that the items are not objects in the database, they're just strings, like this:

```
the_array = ['first', 'second', 'third']
```

Thanks to Lichtamberg, I've done it like this:

```
f.select(:test, options_for_select(Array[*the_array.collect {|v,i| [v,the_array.index(v)] }], :selected => f.object.test)) %>
```

Which gives the desired output:

```
<option value="0">first</option>
<option value="1">second</option>
<option value="2">third</option>
```

I did not use `Hash`, because the order is important, and my ruby version is not greater than 1.9

Comment: just FYI you do not need the `Array[*]` everything inbetween the * and ] will produce the same result.

Answer (score 13):

You can also do this as one line if `the_array = ['first', 'second', 'third']`

```
<%= select "obj", "test", the_array.each_with_index.map {|name, index| [name,index]} %>
```

I have tested this as far back as Rails 2.3.14.

Comment: Change {|name, index| [name, index]} to {|name, index| [name, name]} to make option values ​​as name instead of index.

Comment: @FernandoKosh that's the default behaviour when an Array is passed to `options_for_select`.

Answer (score 7):

### Ruby >= 1.9.3

Ruby has (brilliantly) added a `with_index` method on `map` and `collect` so you can just do the following now:

```ruby
options_for_select( ['first', 'second', 'third'].collect.with_index.to_a )
```

And that'll get you the following HTML:

```html
<option value="0">first</option>
<option value="1">second</option>
<option value="2">third</option>
```

Praise [Matz](https://github.com/matz) et al.

Comment: This is the neatest way!

Answer (score 3):

```
@people = [{:name => "Andy", :id => 1}, {:name => "Rachel", :id => 2}, {:name => "test", :id => 3}]
# or
peop = ["Rachel", "Thomas",..]
@people = Hash[*peop.collect { |v| [v, a.index(v)] }.flatten]
```

and then

```
select_tag "people", options_from_collection_for_select(@people, "name", "id")
# <select id="people" name="people"><option value="1">Andy</option>....</select>
```

Another solution (HAML-Format):

```
=select_tag("myselect")
  =options_for_select(array)
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select

Comment: How could I create the collection `@people` from an array? Suppose I have `['Andy', 'Rachel', 'test']`, or anything else, because I now don't know what array I will get at runtime.

Comment: I don't care about which name is for an id, I'm only interested in the index the user selects. There's an error in your last post: there should be `peop.index(v)` instead of `a.index(v)`. However, I get an error: `undefined method 'name' for ["", 0]:Array`.

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select see my updated post..